# Get details from 2 tables asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating a web api. I have two tables

`Employee_details`

```
SlNo      Employeeid        R_ID
 1         2022             AC1
 2         2023             AC2
```

`Id_details`

```
SlNo        R_ID            L_ID
 1          AC1             L001
 2          AC1             L002
 3          AC1             L003
 4          AC2             L004
 5          AC2             L005
```

I created a web api with RESTful services. I need to get all the L_ID of a particular Employeeid. For example if I request for employeeid 2022 I should get L001 L002 and L003. Help me please. I created the tables using code first and enabling migration

Code

Model class

Employee_details.cs

```
public class Employee_details
{
   public int slNo {get; set;}
   public string Employeeid  {get; set;}
   public string R_ID  {get; set;}

   //Navigation
   public Id_details Id_details{get; set;}
}
```

Id_details.cs

```
public class Id_details
{
   public int slNo {get; set;}
   public string R_ID  {get; set;}
   public string  L_ID {get; set;}

}
```

Controller

```
 public IQueryable<Employee_id> Getdetails(string employeeid )
    {
       return db.Employee_details
           .Where(b => b.Employeeid.Equals(employeeid, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Include(c => c.Id_details);

    }
```

I did not make foreign key reference since R_ID field in Table 2 is not a primary key.

Comment: Add your code what you've tried?

Comment: Simple use of SQL join will solve your problem, Why don't you make a try?

Comment: Using Entity Framework?

Comment: Yes using Entity Framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Native SQL this query is your return data.

```
  SELECT ID.L_ID    
      FROM Id_details AS ID   
     INNER JOIN Employee_details ED 
        ON ID.R_ID =  ED.R_ID  
     WHERE ED.Employeeid = '2022'
```

or if you use EntitiyFramework

this query return equels R_ID records then set Employee_details condition

```
var res = db.Id_details.Join(db.Employee_details, x => x.R_ID , y => y.R_ID , (x, y) => x).ToList();
```

or you can select any R_ID in containsList

```
var conditionList =db.Employee_details.where(p=>p.Employeeid.equals('2022')).select(p=>p.R_ID);
```

then set condition using conditionList search

```
  db.Id_details.where(p=> conditionList.contains(p.R_ID)).select ( ... );
```